# How to setup Angular CLI project to compile Typescript for Express server

Tags: express, typescript, angular-cli

I created an Angular CLI project and followed the excellent [MEAN App with Angular 2 and the Angular CLI](https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli) tutorial to set up an Express server. However the instructions only lay down JavaScript files for the server.

Is there a standard way to alter the Angular CLI configuration to build the server source from Typescript files?

Comment: The angular-cli is going to only build your client-application. It will output the build to a folder named dist at the root of the directory where you ran ng new "projectname".

Comment: Yes, understood, but I would think by now someone would have investigated best practices on how to integrate Angular CLI with Express using TypeScript given they are both part of the MEAN stack.